# Sort lists on value only if at least one duplicate value in both, else sort by another value in a Pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Let's say we have two lists, such that `key1` will never be a duplicate value in their own list, but may be the same in each other(not that both lists must have the same number of elements, but can be dynamic from [1..inf]):

```
list1 = [
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 40
  },
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 45
  },
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 46
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 50
  },
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 55
  },
  {
    'key1': 7,
    'key2': 66
  }
]
```

How can we sort the lists, such that the first element is always a duplicate `key1` value among the lists, until there are no more duplicates, and then sort by `key2` in ascending order.

The logic of the program looks sort of like this:

```
while list1 and list2:

    # sort so both lists are (either duplicate value sorting OR highest value)
    list1.sort... 
    list2.sort...

    var1 = list1.pop
    var2 = list2.pop

    if var1.key2 > var2.key2:
       subtract var1.key2 - var2.key
       list1.append(var1)
    elif var1.key2 < var2.key2:
       subtract var2.key2 - var1.key
       list2.append(var2)
    else var1.key2 == var2.key2:
       no append
```

Sample Example of the while loop above, going through the logic describe above:

```
Loop Iterations:

1. Before Sorting (we have duplicate key1 values, so we need to sort by those):

list1 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 15
  },
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 50
  },
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 100
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 35
  },
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 40
  },
  {
    'key1': 7,
    'key2': 90
  }
]

1. After Sorting:

list1 = [
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 50
  },
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 15
  },
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 100
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 35
  },
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 40
  },
  {
    'key1': 7,
    'key2': 90
  }
]

1. logic iteration (one dict from a list is removed, or two, and key2 is decremented)...


2. Before Sorting (we have duplicate key values, so sort by those):

list1 = [
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 15
  },
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 15
  },
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 100
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 40
  },
  {
    'key1': 7,
    'key2': 90
  }
]

2. After Sorting (Note: as long as we're doing sorting by key1 duplicates, we don't necessarily care about secondary key2 sorting, because those dicts will never leave the list until the duplicates are through):

list1 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 15
  },
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 15
  },
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 100
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 40
  },
  {
    'key1': 7,
    'key2': 90
  }
]

2. logic iteration (one dict from a list is removed, or two)...

3. Before Sorting (no duplicate key1, so sort by key2 ascending):

list1 = [
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 15
  },
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 100
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 25
  },
  {
    'key1': 7,
    'key2': 90
  }
]

3. After Sorting:

list1 = [
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 100
  },
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 15
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'key1': 7,
    'key2': 90
  },
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 25
  }
]

3. logic iteration (one dict from a list is removed, or two)...

4. Before Sorting (no duplicate key1, so sort by key2 ascending):

list1 = [
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 10
  },
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 15
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 25
  }
]

4. After Sorting:

list1 = [
  {
     'key1': 3,
     'key2': 15
  },
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 10
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 25
  }
]

4. logic iteration (one dict from a list is removed, or two)...

5. Before Sorting (no duplicate key1, so sort by key2 ascending):

list1 = [
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 10
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 10
  }
]

5. After Sorting:

list1 = [
  {
    'key1': 5,
    'key2': 10
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'key1': 4,
    'key2': 10
  }
]

Last 2 dicts then cancel each other out with 10 and 10, so loop ends
```

Caveats:

- The "logic" is that we 'subtract' the two `key2` values in each iteration, which is why we either append a single dict or none. But the main problem is "how" we sort the lists to always subtract in the order needed. We need to subtract by `key1` duplicates first, and subtract by highest to lowest value secondly.
- The reason we need to sort by duplicates first, then highest value, is because duplicate subtractions need to happen firsts, and are logged differently than non-duplicate subtractions, which need to happen in a highest-to-lowest order

Comment: Do you want `{'key2': 40, 'key1': 3}` and `{'key2': 50, 'key1': 3}` as popped elements in list1 and list2 ?

Comment: Yes. So the "poppable" elements should always be duplicate key1 values until there are no more, then it should just sort by key2 value.

Comment: But you have two duplicate key1's in your list right ? You want to remove 2 or just last one ? And after removing you want to club both the lists and sort it using key2 ?

Comment: Please remove your "sort of" logic; it can't work as written, and only confuses things.

Comment: @jake: Question doesn't has enough information . request you to re-phrase your question with examples

Comment: I've added more information, sample input and output of the hypothetical program

Answer (score -1):

This always only appends one of the duplicates to one of the lists, chosen by doing `somelogic`:

```
def somelogic( a, b ):
    if a['key1']==4:
        return (0,b)
    else:
        return (1,a)

prev = (None,)
matches = [[],[]]
extra = [[],[]]
for k in sorted(([(x['key1'],0,x) for x in list1] + [(x['key1'],1,x) for x in list2])):
    if k[0] == prev[0]:
        which = somelogic( k[2], prev[2] )
        matches[which[0]].append( which[1] )
        prev = (None,)
    else:
        if prev[0] != None:
            extra[prev[1]].append(prev[2])
        prev = k
if prev[0] != None:
    extra[prev[1]].append(prev[2])

list1 = matches[0] + sorted(extra[0],key=lambda r: -r['key2'])
list2 = matches[1] + sorted(extra[1],key=lambda r: -r['key2'])
```

Comment: in terms of `if a['key1']==4:` keep in mind that the values for key1 and key2 can be dynamic, so the lists above are examples, but future lists maybe have many more values such as `list1 = [{key1: 10, key2: 1000}, {key1: 20, key2: 1000}...]` But I see that you're building a list with the matches out in front and the sorted behind

Comment: Information not included in the question cannot be expected to influence the answers.

Answer (score -1):

If I've read the question right, you want to sort the list like requested inside each loop, with your pop/logic/append. Here I'll just give some logic to do the sort. We can do this with a couple list comprehensions:

```
#first find list1 which are in list 2, and vice versa. Sort these by key1, so that they will match up.
list1matches = sorted([i for i in list1 if i['key1'] in [i['key1'] for i in list2]], key = lambda x: x.get('key1'))
list2matches = sorted([i for i in list2 if i['key1'] in [i['key1'] for i in list1]], key = lambda x: x.get('key1'))

#find non matches, sort by key2
list1non = sorted([i for i in list1 if i not in list1matches], key = lambda x: x.get('key2'))
list2non = sorted([i for i in list2 if i not in list2matches], key = lambda x: x.get('key2'))

#rebuild the lists
list1 = list1matches + list1non
list2 = list2matches + list2non
```

Comment: It doesn't produce the example output on the example input.

Comment: sure, this is just taking care of the `list1.sort... (either duplicate value sorting OR highest value)` and `list2.sort... (either duplicate value sorting OR highest value)` part, the OP has the rest in the loop in the Q

Comment: No, it doesn't, and even if it did, OP's loop won't work.

Comment: I guess I've read it wrong - my understanding is op wants to sort their two lists as above, take the first var from each list, test them, use 1 and add one back to the list for reuse, then continue until they are all done. Seems like we need a better question :)